# Orientation change ignored in Android AVD

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-orientation

I set up the Android SDK in Eclipse on Linux and I am trying some AVDs. I have created a 2.3.3 (API 10) device and a 4.1 (API 16) device. Both use the default values provided in the dialog box for creation.

When I run the 2.3.3 AVD and press ctrl + F11 to change orientation, the orientation of the screen changes from portrait to landscape and the keyboard moves below the screen BUT all activities (mine as well as the standard apps) continue to be drawn in portrait mode. The configuration change does not seem to be registered and handled.

The 4.1 AVD works as expected: the screen orientation changes and the running Activities are terminated and redrawn in layout-land.

Is this a bug or a configuration issue that I can fix?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's a bug: [Issue 13189: Orientation does not change from landscape to portrait on Emulator on 2.3](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13189)  It's was fixed for AVD images post 2.3.3, but it seems the fix was never backported to 2.3.x

The work around is to add *Keyboard support* as a hardware property to Gingerbread AVDs, though as noted in the bug report, this isn't perfect.